# Двойные ключи в MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Я создал ключ

```
KEY `login_in` (`login`,`password`)
```

Для выборки по сочетанию "логин пароль".
Нужно ли создавать отдельный ключ для выборки только по логину?

Answer (score 1):

Разные пользователи с одинаковым логином - не лучшая идея.

Comment: Я обращаюсь к ключу "логин пароль" при авторизации, а при sity.ru/user только к логину, т.е. получаю данные о юзере при входе на его профиль. При чем тут пользователи с одним логином?

Comment: > При чем тут пользователи с одним логином?

Если логин уникальный, то смысла в составном индексе в этом случае нет. Достаточно кластерного индекса по логину.
А если у вас создан составной индекс (некластерный), то отдельного индекса по логину не нужно. А вот по паролю может пригодиться. :-)